# Compact sets of the complex plane with countable boundary

Tags: general-topology, complex-numbers

Suppose $E$ is a compact set of the complex plane and the boundary of $E$ is a countable set. How does one prove that $E$ is equal to its boundary?

Comment: what is meaning of boundary?

Comment: @Paul [Boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The boundary of non-empty bounded open sets in the plane is always uncountable. Conclude that $E$ has an empty interior.

Comment: Nitpicking: of nonempty bounded open sets.

Comment: julien, thanks. I seem to forget the $0$ case today. I must be hungry...

Comment: @AsafKaragila how can I show that?